# I want to create a second button but it doesn't appear - Xcode 6 Swift

Tags: xcode, button, swift

This is the code I am using, however the second button "score" doesn't appear when I test the app, why?

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let playbutton = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "play")
    let score = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "score")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.playbutton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(self.playbutton)
        self.backgroundColor  = UIColor(hex: 0x80D9FF)

    func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.score.position = CGPointMake(180, 100)
        self.addChild(self.score)
        self.backgroundColor  = UIColor(hex: 0x80D9FF)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you ever call the second didMoveToView() ? Have you tried including the code to add score in original override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) like this :

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let playbutton = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "play")
    let score = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "score")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.playbutton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(self.playbutton)
        self.backgroundColor  = UIColor(hex: 0x80D9FF)

        self.score.position = CGPointMake(180, 100)
        self.addChild(self.score)
        self.backgroundColor  = UIColor(hex: 0x80D9FF)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me so much time :)

Comment: Hi Andy, do you know what the code would be if I wanted to link both of these buttons to two different scenes?